# Find the primitive function of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(2n+2)}{n!}(x-1)^{2n+1}$

Tags: calculus, integration, summation, power-series, indefinite-integrals

> Find the primitive function of
>   $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(2n+2)}{n!}(x-1)^{2n+1}$

**My attempt:**

In order to integrate, I'm trying to find the radius of convergence:

Let $t=(x-1) \Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(2n+2)}{n!}t^{2n+1}$

$$  a_n =
\begin{cases}
\frac{(-1)^k(2k+2)}{k!},  & \text{$n = 2k+1$} \\
0, & \text{else}
\end{cases}$$

$$  \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} =
\begin{cases}
(\frac{2k+2}{k!})^{\frac{1}{2k+1}},  & \text{$n = 2k+1$} \\
0, & \text{else}
\end{cases}$$

Hence, one of the partial limits is zero and the other:

$$\lim_{k \to \infty}{(\frac{2k+2}{k!})^{\frac{1}{2k+1}}}=0^0=??$$

Comment: Integrate first; worry about convergence later!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(2n+4)}{(n+1)!}(x-1)^{2n+3}}{\frac{(-1)^n(2n+2)}{n!}(x-1)^{2n+1}}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n+4}{2n+2}\times\frac1{n+1}|x-1|^2=0.$$Therefore, the series converges everywhere. A primitive will be$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}(x-1)^{2n+2}.$$

Comment: And this primitive (as you wrote it) can be written as closed-form, recalling that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{ t^{n+2}}{n!} = t^2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-t)^n}{n!} = t^2 (e^{-t}-1)$.

Comment: @ClementC. Nice remark!

Comment: Thanks! How can you use the ratio test if it's defined for a series such as: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n(x-a)^n$ but in this case the exponent is $2n+1$ ?

Comment: @Ro168 The ratio test is defined for *any* series of non-zero numbers, not just for power series.